# Is the Choice of Scale Effects Limited per Roll or per Conflict?

Tags: attack, fate, fate-core, defense, scale

System Toolkit page 67 offers the Scale mechanics for attacks and defences between different-sized opponents, groups etc. However, I'm not sure how to interpret inner 'or' (i.e. the 'or' within each of the two effects).

Specifically, when it says to apply a bonus to attack *or* defence, does it mean that only one of the two can be used within the *same roll* (since one is an attacker and another is a defender), or does it mean that the side which benefited from a +2 to harm done should *not* receive the harm reduction in the *same conflict*? (The same question applies to the attack/defence skill bonus.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Per-roll application of scale is more in line with [the Golden Rule](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/what-do-during-play#the-golden-rule).

It is also consistent with practical implementation in published systems.

### The Toolkit is not a rulebook.

The Toolkit's description of scale is ambiguous as to whether scale is determined and applied globally per-conflict or individually per-roll: while it says that scale comes into play when the entities "enter into a conflict," the specific effect applies "to the defense roll." The definite article implies a per-roll determination of applicability.

But the Toolkit presents ideas to incorporate into games, not pre-made modules ready to plug into any system. Rather than argue semantics on a system that's never been interested in nit-picking verbiage as a way to determine what's right to do, I looked at two recent games I have which *use* scale-like effects.

Both Fate of Agaptus and Dresden Files Accelerated use scale-like effects, and both of them are clear that scale is applied only to actions where the narrative source of the scale is applicable to the kind of action being rolled.